# Simple HTML and CSS Question - Text Align Not Working?

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to basic web markup languages. I'm working through an online course and am struggling to .mainfooter-links in the CSS file to align to the centre. I would be grateful if someone could take a couple of minutes to look through the code and tell me where I have gone wrong. Thanks In Advance.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

#product-overview {
    background: url("freedom.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.section-title {
    color: #2ddf5c;
    text-align: center;
}

#product-overview h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

.plan  {

  Background: #d5ffdc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.plan--highlighted {

  background: #19b84c;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);enter code here
}

.plan__annotation {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: darkgreen;
  padding: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.75);

}

.plan__title {
  color: #0e4f1f;


}

.plan__price {
  color: #858585;

}

.plan--highlighted .plan__title{
  color: white;

}

.plan--highlighted .plan__price{
  color: #0e4f1f;

}

#Planlist {

  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.0;

}

.button {
  background: #0e4f1f;
  color: white;
  font: inherit; /**Inherit font-family and not default**/
  border: solid 2px #0e4f1f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer; /**Creates a hand when moved over the
  button**/
}

.button:hover,
.button:active {
  background:white;
  color: #0e4f1f;
}

.button:focus{
  outline: none;
}

#Key-Features{

  background: #ff1b68;
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 60px;

}

#Key-Features .SectionFeatures-Title{

  color: white;
  margin: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Key-Feature-List{

  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.Key-Feature-Style{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px;
  width: 30%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.Key-Feature-Image{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffcede;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 2px solid #424242;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:auto;
}





/* h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
} */

.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #2ddf5c;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}

.main-header > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-header__brand {
    color: #0e4f1f;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.main-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: calc(100% - 74px);
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-nav__items {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.main-nav__item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 16px;
}

.main-nav__item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0e4f1f;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

.main-nav__item a:hover,
.main-nav__item a:active {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}

.main-nav__item--cta a {
    color: white;
    background: #ff1b68;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.main-nav__item--cta a:hover,
.main-nav__item--cta a:active {
    color: #ff1b68;
    background: white;
    border: none;
}


.main-footer {
  background: black;
  padding: 32px;
  margin-top: 48px;

}

.main-footer-links {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;


}



.main-footer-link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 16px;


}


.main-footer-link a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-footer-link a:hover,
.main-footer-link a:active
{ color: #ccc;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>uHost</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="main-header">
        <div>
            <a href="index.html" class="main-header__brand">
                uHost
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul class="main-nav__items">
                <li class="main-nav__item">
                    <a href="packages/index.html">Packages</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav__item">
                    <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav__item main-nav__item--cta">
                    <a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="product-overview">
            <h1>Get the freedom you deserve.</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="plans">
            <h1 class="section-title">Choose Your Plan</h1>
              <div>

                <!--Plan One-->

                <article class="plan">
                  <h1 class="plan__title">Free</h1>
                  <h2 class="plan__price">£0/month</h2>
                  <h3>For Hobby Projects or Small Teams</h3>
                  <ul id="Planlist">
                    <div>
                      <li>1 Workspace</li>
                      <li>Unlimited Traffic</li>
                      <li>10GB Storage</li>
                      <li>Online Forum Support</li>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
                    <div>
                    <Button class="button">Choose Plan</Button>
                    </div>
                </article>

                  <!--Plan Two-->

                <article class="plan plan--highlighted">
                  <h1 class="plan__annotation">RECOMMENDED</h1>
                  <h1 class="plan__title">PLUS</h1>
                  <h2 class="plan__price">£29.99/month</h2>
                  <h3>For Ambitious Projects</h3>
                  <ul id="Planlist">
                    <div>
                      <li>5 Workspace</li>
                      <li>Unlimited Traffic</li>
                      <li>100GB Storage</li>
                      <li>Telephone and Email Support</li>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
                    <div>
                    <Button class="button">Choose Plan</Button>
                    </div>
                </article>

                  <!--Plan Three-->

                <article class="plan">
                  <h1 class="plan__title">Snoopsy Ninja Mode</h1>
                  <h2 class="plan__price">£99.99/month</h2>
                  <h3>Your Enterprise Solution</h3>
                  <ul id="Planlist">
                    <div>
                      <li>100 Workspace</li>
                      <li>Unlimited Traffic</li>
                      <li>5TB Storage</li>
                      <li>24/7 Pooky Ninja Support</li>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
                    <div>
                    <Button class="button">Choose Plan</Button>
                    </div>
                </article>

              </div>
        </section>
        <section id="Key-Features">
          <h1 class="SectionFeatures-Title">Many Good Reasons to Stick Around</h1>

          <ul class="Key-Feature-List">

            <li class="Key-Feature-Style">
              <div class="Key-Feature-Image">

              </div>
              <p>3,857,000 Trusting Customers</p>
            </li>

            <li class="Key-Feature-Style">

              <div class="Key-Feature-Image">

              </div>
              <p>99.999% Uptime Guarantee</p>
            </li>

            <li class="Key-Feature-Style">

              <div class="Key-Feature-Image">

              </div>
              <p>Lightning Fast CDN</p>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </section>

    </main>
</body>

<footer class="main-footer">
  <nav>
    <ul class"main-footer-links">
      <li class="main-footer-link">
        <a href="#">Support</a>
      </li>
      <li class="main-footer-link">
        <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with an emphasis on *minimal*. You also appear to have HTML code after your `</body>` tag which is invalid.

Comment: Replace `class"main-footer-links"` with this `class = "main-footer-links"`

Comment: Choosing to close vote as off-topic as errors caused by typos

Answer (score 3):

there is a error in your class name definition, replace the:

```
<ul class"main-footer-links">
```

with

```
<ul class="main-footer-links">
```

you've missed the = sign :)

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot an equal character '='
change `<ul class"main-footer-links">` to `<ul class="main-footer-links">`

Answer (score 0):

@NoobLearns please include the css property `text-align: center` to class `.main-footer{ } or .main-footer-links{ }`, that will align the list items to center, and also use some better code editor like `vscode` to avoid mistakes like missing `=` etc as suggested by others here.

```css
.Key-Feature-List,
.Key-Feature-Style,
.plan {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center
}
#Planlist,
.Key-Feature-List,
.Key-Feature-Style,
.plan,
.section-title {
  text-align: center
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}
#product-overview {
  background: url(freedom.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 528px;
  padding: 10px
}
.section-title {
  color: #2ddf5c
}
#product-overview h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Anton, sans-serif
}
.plan {
  Background: #d5ffdc;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: middle
}
.plan--highlighted {
  background: #19b84c;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
.plan__annotation {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #006400;
  padding: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba (0, 0, 0, .75)
}
.plan__title {
  color: #0e4f1f
}
.plan__price {
  color: #858585
}
.plan--highlighted .plan__title {
  color: #fff
}
.plan--highlighted .plan__price {
  color: #0e4f1f
}
#Planlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2
}
.button {
  background: #0e4f1f;
  color: #fff;
  font: inherit;
  border: 2px solid #0e4f1f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer
}
.button:active,
.button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #0e4f1f
}
.button:focus {
  outline: 0
}
#Key-Features {
  background: #ff1b68;
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 60px
}
#Key-Features .SectionFeatures-Title {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 32px;
  text-align: center
}
.Key-Feature-List {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-content: center
}
.Key-Feature-Style {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px;
  width: 30%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder
}
.main-header>div,
.main-nav {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block
}
.main-header__brand,
.main-nav__item a {
  color: #0e4f1f;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none
}
.Key-Feature-Image {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffcede;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 2px solid #424242;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto
}
.main-header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #2ddf5c;
  padding: 8px 16px
}
.main-header__brand {
  font-size: 22px
}
.main-nav {
  text-align: right;
  width: calc(100% - 74px)
}
.main-nav__items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}
.main-nav__item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 16px
}
.main-nav__item a {
  padding: 3px 0
}
.main-nav__item a:active,
.main-nav__item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff
}
.main-nav__item--cta a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff1b68;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px
}
.main-nav__item--cta a:active,
.main-nav__item--cta a:hover {
  color: #ff1b68;
  background: #fff;
  border: none
}
.main-footer {
  background: #000;
  padding: 32px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  text-align: center
}
.main-footer-links {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center
}
.main-footer-link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 16px
}
.main-footer-link a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none
}
.main-footer-link a:active,
.main-footer-link a:hover {
  color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div><a href="index.html" class="main-header__brand">
      uHost
    </a></div>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav__items">
      <li class="main-nav__item"><a href="packages/index.html">Packages</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav__item"><a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav__item main-nav__item--cta"><a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <section id="product-overview">
    <h1>Get the freedom you deserve.</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="plans">
    <h1 class="section-title">Choose Your Plan</h1>
    <div>
      <article class="plan">
        <h1 class="plan__title">Free</h1>
        <h2 class="plan__price">£0/month</h2>
        <h3>For Hobby Projects or Small Teams</h3>
        <ul id="Planlist">
          <div>
            <li>1 Workspace</li>
            <li>Unlimited Traffic</li>
            <li>10GB Storage</li>
            <li>Online Forum Support</li>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <div><Button class="button">Choose Plan</Button></div>
      </article>
      <article class="plan plan--highlighted">
        <h1 class="plan__annotation">RECOMMENDED</h1>
        <h1 class="plan__title">PLUS</h1>
        <h2 class="plan__price">£29.99/month</h2>
        <h3>For Ambitious Projects</h3>
        <ul id="Planlist">
          <div>
            <li>5 Workspace</li>
            <li>Unlimited Traffic</li>
            <li>100GB Storage</li>
            <li>Telephone and Email Support</li>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <div><Button class="button">Choose Plan</Button></div>
      </article>
      <article class="plan">
        <h1 class="plan__title">Snoopsy Ninja Mode</h1>
        <h2 class="plan__price">£99.99/month</h2>
        <h3>Your Enterprise Solution</h3>
        <ul id="Planlist">
          <div>
            <li>100 Workspace</li>
            <li>Unlimited Traffic</li>
            <li>5TB Storage</li>
            <li>24/7 Pooky Ninja Support</li>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <div><Button class="button">Choose Plan</Button></div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Key-Features">
    <h1 class="SectionFeatures-Title">Many Good Reasons to Stick Around</h1>
    <ul class="Key-Feature-List">
      <li class="Key-Feature-Style">
        <div class="Key-Feature-Image"></div>
        <p>3,857,000 Trusting Customers</p>
      </li>
      <li class="Key-Feature-Style">
        <div class="Key-Feature-Image"></div>
        <p>99.999% Uptime Guarantee</p>
      </li>
      <li class="Key-Feature-Style">
        <div class="Key-Feature-Image"></div>
        <p>Lightning Fast CDN</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
<footer class="main-footer">
  <nav>
    <ul class="main-footer-links">
      <li class="main-footer-link"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li class="main-footer-link"><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a '=' in your code:

```
<ul class="main-footer-links">
```

also try adding text align to:

```
.main-footer-link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 16px;
  text-align: center;

}
```